# How to apply lock on key in ignite Cache? Is it possible to apply lock on read operation through ignite cache for perticular key?

Tags: java, ignite

**How to fullfill following Requirement :**
1. For get operation on Ignite cache establish lock on specific key.
2. During this process, key should not be accessible for get operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth taking a look at REPEATABLE_READ PESSIMISTIC [transactions](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.1/docs/transactions#section-pessimistic-transactions)
Implicit transactions should provide the same guarantees.
As a less preferable option you may consider [explicit locks](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.1/docs/distributed-locks)

Comment: Can you provide any example related to this this ?

Comment: Have you checked the links (those colored in blue) from my previous comment?

Comment: Yes, I have checked.    1)In explicit lock object is readable after applied lock on that particular key.   2)In transactions Can we apply this on key ?

Comment: 1) It's readable from an implicit transaction because it's OPTIMISTIC READ_COMMITTED, but a PESSIMISTIC REPEATABLE_READ transaction will wait on a lock to become free.  
2) As a rule of thumb, you should not use explicit locks within explicit transactions, instead, you should rely on the semantics provided by the transaction itself.

Comment: Since it's worked for you, kindly accept the answer so that it was vivid to other users.